# Setting up a "garage sale" on sharepoint

Tags: development, page-layout, content-database

Our company is looking to sell a number of retired electronics (computers, etc). Previously we would have someone manually monitor and make sales, however this has proven to be inefficient in a large company like ours.

We're looking to build a page on sharepoint where people can:

- See available stock
- See when stock is unavailable
- Reserve a device(s) for purchase

I'm new to sharepoint but keen to make this project happen and looking for some pointers- what would be the best way to start on developing a page that does something like this?

Comment: This question really isn't focussed enough. But as a start may isuggest that you indicate what version of SharePoint you are using

Answer (score 1):

Create a list. Call it "Asset Type". Create fields for Model, Description, and tech specs (or whatever), and Starting Inventory.

Create a "Claims" list where people can add a list item to claim a resource. Create a lookup field to the Asset type list to allow people to choose what they want. Add a field to indicate if the user has received the asset. Group the claims list by Asset Type. To determine availability just cross reference the number of claims for that asset against the starting inventory. For extra credit you can write code to calculate remaining inventory but you can go live without that.

If you are new to SharePoint this is a great low-risk starter project and I'd encourage you to tinker with it and improve it incrementally as you learn.

Comment: Since the OP mentioned selling the items, a "price" field would be a good idea. I'd also have a Person-type field to allow someone to put their name as buyer.